# .htaccess redirect all urls with a specific string variation

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

My site is having a problem with Google bot. 
In webmasters tools google is showing 404 errors for pages that are nowhere to be found.

The pattern of error pages is simple, it is like this

```
Domain.com/post-type-1
Domain.com/post-type-2
Domain.com/post-type-3
Domain.com/category/x/post-type-1
Domain.com/category/x/post-type-2
Domain.com/category/x/post-type-3
Domain.com/category/y/post-type-1
Domain.com/category/y/post-type-2
```

I want to know how I can redirect this all these errors at once via .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place this redirect at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule (?:^|/)post-type-\d+ /? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. Can you please tell me if this redirect should be placed above other redirects in .htaccess?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant by writing `at top of your .htaccess`. Keep this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks for your answer.